# Why hashcode and equals method does not work with ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, hash

If you run following code, hashmap denies the duplicate but ArrayList accepts the duplicate.

Why arraylist also denies the duplicate using hashcode() and equals() method ?

```js
public class EmpData {

 int Id; 
 String FirstName; 
 String LastName;
  
 
 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
  final int prime = 31;
  int result = 1;
  result = prime * result + ((FirstName == null) ? 0 : FirstName.hashCode());
  result = prime * result + Id;
  result = prime * result + ((LastName == null) ? 0 : LastName.hashCode());
  return result;
 }



 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (this == obj)
   return true;
  if (obj == null)
   return false;
  if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
   return false;
  
  EmpData other = (EmpData) obj;
  if (FirstName == null) {
   if (other.FirstName != null)
    return false;
  } else if (!FirstName.equals(other.FirstName))
   return false;
  if (Id != other.Id)
   return false;
  if (LastName == null) {
   if (other.LastName != null)
    return false;
  } else if (!LastName.equals(other.LastName))
   return false;
  
  return true;
 }

 


 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "EmpData [Id=" + Id + ", FirstName=" + FirstName + ", LastName=" + LastName + "] \n";
 }



 public EmpData(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
  Id = id;
  FirstName = firstName;
  LastName = lastName;
 }



 public static void main(String[] args) {
     
  EmpData obj1 = new EmpData(1,"Mk","Jk");
  EmpData obj2 = new EmpData(1,"Mk","Jk");
  
     Map<EmpData,String> myMap = new HashMap<>(); myMap.put(obj1, "First");
  myMap.put(obj2, "Second");
   
  System.out.println("Hashmap values are: " + myMap);
  
  ArrayList<EmpData> newArray = new ArrayList<>();
 
  newArray.add(obj1);  
  newArray.add(obj2);
  
  System.out.println("Array values are: " + newArray);
 
 }

}
```

Above code gives following output:

```
Hashmap values are: {EmpData [Id=1, FirstName=Mk, LastName=Jk] 
=Second}
Array values are: [EmpData [Id=1, FirstName=Mk, LastName=Jk] 
, EmpData [Id=1, FirstName=Mk, LastName=Jk] 
]
```

How I can make the Arraylist make use of hascode() and equals() method ? 
Is it the case that hashcode and equals method are only used with the hashmap ?

Comment: Allowing duplicates is in the very definition of a list.

Comment: @user2746466 What you want is a `HashSet<>`, not an `ArrayList`.

Comment: But can i make use of hashcode and equals method for ArrayList as of HashMap ?

Comment: Not without creating your own implementation of List, which I **strongly** recommend against. Just use a `HashSet<>`

Comment: OK.......... so hashcode and equals methods are used only for collections which use hash functions ???

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` does use `equals()` when you call methods such as `int indexOf(Object o)` and `boolean remove(Object o);`, but it never uses `hashCode()` and it allows the presence of duplicate elements.

It doesn't matter if you override `hashCode` and `equals` or not. Even if you added `obj1` multiple times to the `ArrayList`, you will end up with a `List` having multiple references to the same object.

You can use a `HashSet` (or a `LinkedHashSet`) if you want to eliminate duplicates.